# Warning : update in state transition when accessing the app via a callback page and updating the Context from here

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have an app composed of two pages, a Home page and a Callback page. After authentication on a tiers service, such as a social network or other, the user is redirected to the Callback page of my app. The app uses the react-context api and I would like to store all the data found in the query string of the callback page. Shortly I want to open a page of my app, not the home page, and update the context of the app from this page.

This is what is achieved in [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/role-based-access-control-rbac-and-react-apps/) for Auth0. The app is composed of 5 very short files, I will reproduce them here.

The problem is that I get a warning when I access `http://127.0.0.1:3000/callback` in a browser. The warning is `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`
In the [Auth0 tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/role-based-access-control-rbac-and-react-apps/), this warning doesn't show up but the state update is made within a dedicated function, I don't know how to reproduce this work with my own components.

To reproduce the warning, use `create-react-app` and use the files at the end of the post.
The goal of this toy example is to set `unused_data` in the state of Context component, but without triggering the warning (`unused_data` is actually set).

EDIT : Well, I learned redux and everything works fine when I use redux, so I still don't know why I got an error, but everything is just so much simpler now :)

---

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Context from "./Context";
import Callback from './Callback'
import Home from './Home'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Context>
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/callback" component={Callback} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </Context>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

Context.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Provider} from "./contextDefs";


class Context extends Component {
  state = {
    unused_data: ""
  };

  changeState = () => {
    this.setValue()
  }

  setValue = () => {
    this.setState({
      unused_data: "has been set up",
    })
  }

  render() {
    const providerValue = {
      ...this.state,
      changeState: this.changeState,
    };
    return (
      <Provider value={providerValue}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default Context;
```

---

Callback.js

```
import React from "react";
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

import {Consumer} from "./contextDefs";

const callback = props => (
  <Consumer>
    {({changeState}) => {
        changeState();
        return <Redirect to="/"/>;
      }
    }
  </Consumer>
)

export default callback;
```

---

contextDefs.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const Context = createContext({
    unused_data: "",
    changeState: () => {},
  });

export const Provider = Context.Provider;
export const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
```

---

Home.js

```
import React from "react";

const AuthTwitter = props =>  {
  return (
  <div>
    Test
  </div>
  );
}

export default AuthTwitter;
```